# How do I bindParam when I am manually applying regular expressions which require quotes for %?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a MySQL statement. The variable clause has the `where` clause. The query was working fine until I used bindParam. From the documentation, there have been instances of `LIKE` being used. However, I am still unclear as to why my query returns null. I think the flaw is in using the `:tag` in the `$clause`.

```
 public function findAllByTag($tag)
    {
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM Conditions WHERE  ";
        $clause = "(tag LIKE ':tag,%' || tag LIKE '%,:tag' || tag LIKE '%,:tag,%' || tag LIKE ':tag')";
        $query .= $clause;
        $boundParams[0] = $query;
        $stmt           = $this->getPreparedStatement($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':tag', $tag, \PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
        $stmt->execute($boundParams);
        $collection = new Collection();
        while ($data = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $collection->add($this->createObject($data));
        }
        $collection->resetChanges();
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: You can only use the `:tag` alias once. So if you have multiple you should use `:tag1`, `:tag2`, `:tag3`, etc.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think that it is wrong (I've tested that). The problem come from the fact that the OP `:tag` are wrapped by single quotes. Using `:tag` multiple times is OK.

Comment: @Syscall __no__, you can use name for a placeholder only once.

Comment: @u_mulder I've tested : `'select * from words WHERE word=:word or word=concat(:word,"y")'` with parameters : `[':word'=>'cloud']`. It works : returns `cloud` and `cloudy`.

Comment: Then there's something wrong in a manual, I suupose

Comment: **Or** in your code `emulation mode is on`.

Comment: Sorry, I was gone for a little while. Yes, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php states that you can use 'named parameter marker' multiple times when emulation mode is on. I wouldn't switch that on, however, it is less secure: https://michaelseiler.net/2016/07/04/dont-emulate-prepared-statements-pdo-mysql

Comment: And how can I use this in my case? I have to use where tag like '$tag,%' and so on as depicted in the code sample.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks a lot for precisions!

Comment: @u_mulder

Could you please help me out here?
I need to know how can I use the ticks in my case where there are multiple OR cases and regular expression to be used?

Also, you should not mark this question as a duplicate since it is not! The link that you have provided does not cover my question.

Comment: What u_mulder means is that you cannot place `:tag` inside quotes. So `'%,:tag'` won't work because `:tag` will become just part of that string. Use `'CONCAT('%,',:tag)` instead.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware hi, I tried your way and it throws me an error.
Error is:
Syntax error: unexpected ':' expecting  ']'

Comment: I see an unintended quote in front of my CONCAT, but that wouldn't cause that error. Since I have no idea what your query now looks like I cannot help you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware 
My query is: CONCAT('%,',:tag) instead of the current one listed in the question.
Or can you help me form the query?

Comment: I cannot help you. Why not rework you code and, if you cannot work out the cause of the error, ask a new question?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks
Just in case: my code is: https://pastebin.com/0XP7ye4d

Comment: Your question is marked as duplicate, I cannot provide an answer. However, it seems like you're looking for one element of a set. Your query could be: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(seach,list);`. I cannot solve your problem with placeholders here, it requires a longer answer. Start by not using the name 'tag' for two completely different things in the same function, it is very confusing.